# Как завершить поток QThread через сигрнал?

Tags: python, pyqt5

у меня есть поток

```
class InstaBot(QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self,username,password,browser,amount,media_per,follow,like,comment_count,comment,user,user_count,following,liking,
         commenting, parent = None):
    super(InstaBot, self).__init__(parent)
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    self.browser = browser
    self.amount = int(amount)
    self.media_per = int(media_per)
    self.follow = int(follow)
    self.like = int(like)
    self.comment = comment
    self.comment_count = int(comment_count)
    self.user = str(user)
    self.user_count = int(user_count)
    self.following = following
    self.liking = liking
    self.commenting = commenting

  def run(self):
    session = InstaPy(username=f"{self.username}", password=f"{self.password}", headless_browser=self.browser)
    telegram = InstaPyTelegramBot(token='',
                    telegram_username='',
                    instapy_session=session)
    session.login()
    session.set_user_interact(amount=self.amount, randomize=True, percentage=self.media_per, media='Photo')
    session.set_do_follow(enabled=self.following, percentage=self.follow)
    session.set_do_like(enabled=self.liking, percentage=self.like)
    session.set_comments([self.comment])
    session.set_do_comment(enabled=self.commenting, percentage=self.comment_count)
    session.interact_user_followers([f"{self.user}"], amount=self.user_count, randomize=True)
    session.end()
```

сейчас кнопка стоп делает terminate(). а как через кнопку стоп заввершить функцию передачей session.end()

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что значит: "через кнопку стоп завершить функцию передачей session.end()"? Покажите структуру вашего приложения. Было бы проще, если вы составите [mcve]

Comment: У Вас метод `run` без цикла. Так что поток завершается сразу после `session.end`. А так же переопределение `run` ломает цикл событий потока и механизм `сигнал-слот` перестаёт для него работать.